# Sorted MultiIndex DataFrame indexig by index number

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I've a MultiIndex DataFrame as follows:

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['#'],
                                     ['TE', 'SS', 'M', 'MR']])
dat = ([[100, 20, 21, 35], [100, 12, 5, 15]])
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, index=['JC', 'TTo'], columns=header)
df = df.stack()
df = df.sort_values('#', ascending=False).sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False)
```

[image]

And I want to get the next rows indexig by index number not by name, that is the third row of every level 0 index:

```
JC   M   21
TTo  SS  12
```

Of all that I have tried, what is closest to what I am looking for is:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, df.index[2]], '#']
```

But this doesn't work also as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
df["idx"] = df[df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() == 2]
df.loc[df.idx == 2]
```

One line solution from Quang Hoang:

```py
df[df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() == 2]
```

Comment: You can just do `df[df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()==2]`.

Comment: Yes that too, and a thousand other ways ;)

Comment: My point is that you don't need to modify your dataframe, which may trigger a full memory copy.

Comment: @QuangHoang `df[df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()==2]` that was exactly what I need, just one line of code, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `df.xs`:

```
df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1,append=True).xs(3,level=2)
```

---

```
         #
JC  M   21
TTo SS  12
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby` then

```
out = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[2]])
Out[141]: 
             #
JC  JC  SS  20
TTo TTo SS  12
```